# Get-azdisk is giving Tier only premium disks?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-machine

Get-azdisk -disk diskname -resourcegroup RG is providing tier for premium but not showing the tier of standard HDD drives Any idea why?

Thanks,

Comment: Get-AzDisk returns the specifications for an existing disk. Is that what you're intending?

Comment: Yes..but it doesn't show the tier of standard HDD ones.but shows for premium

Comment: Yes, you are correct @ArunCO. I have opened the issue in azure disks-powerShell command `Get-AzDisk` official forum. #[106167](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/106167) with my test cases

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct @ArunCO. I have opened the issue in azure disks-powerShell command  `Get-AzDisk`  official forum of Azure Disk Storage #[106167](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/106167) with my test cases.

**Command**:

```
$disk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $diskName
$disk.Tier
```

[image]

This issue is migrated to MS Q&A Forum by the MSFT User and please follow-up on the Issue No #[1186767](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1186767/size-performance-tier-not-showing-for-the-storage) for the good resolution/fix.